# Online java applet that reads and writes from/to a mySQL database?

Tags: java, php, jquery, mysql

I'm considering creating a little chatbot that learns from users, similar to Clever-Bot (but very different in the way it learns), but I need a way to interface whatever language I use, with mySQL.

I was thinking that java would be the smarter option, though after hunting around it seems a bit difficult to integrate it with a server. Is this true? If not, how would I go about doing that?

Otherwise, would it be smarter to use JavaScript/jQuery/PHP? I'm quite good with these and haven't got a whole lot of experience with Java (but it would be good practise).

Thoughts?

Comment: use ajax with any language of your choice

Comment: Thanks! But how would I get my java applet to speak to AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating chat bots, consider [AIML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIML). And an interpreter that would help you use your AIML files. Going for a backend database isn't a good thing I would say, since AIML is built for Artificial Intelligence stuff,chat bot in your case. Most of the famous chat bots on the Internet use AIML, example [A.L.I.C.E](http://alice.pandorabots.com/) .

Comment: Thanks Kazekage, but this wont be a normal chatbot, and so I cant use that language.

Comment: What do you mean by a normal chatbot? You can specialize it the way you want, and it can learn automatically too. That's the wonder of AIML.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I'll look further into this, though my bot isn't really a chatbot, so I probably shouldn't have mentioned that.